# How do I filter audio with modified spectrogram?

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing

Say I computed Short Time Fourier Transform or Spectrogram of some audio input using `scipy.signal.stft` or `scipy.signal.spectrogram`.

Is there an easy way in python to use it as a filter for my audio input to produce an other audio which would basically be just silence or very near to that?

In practice I would modify that spectrogram before applying it back to the audio to filter out only some audio information.

Answer (score 0):

A spectrogram is lossy (does not preserve necessary phase information), thus cannot be used to recreate the input signal (or a filtered variant).